# Repeatedly running a background script in Rails3/Heroku Cedar deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am developing a Rails3 app which will run on Heroku Cedar stack and needs to constantly check for new tweets under a certain hashtag. I have the logic to do this in place but I would like to run this task in the background so as not to interfere with the main app performance. I also need to write any new tweets found to a database so I will need access to Active Record. I am looking for advise on what might be the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar, it doesn't matter for me if tweets are slightly out of date - we use the scheduler for 10 minute executions of a rake task which is watching a hashtag. We can change the frequency of the executing to hourly/daily should we feel 10 mins is too frequent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I considered using the scheduler addon but the 10min frequency isn't adequate for what I need and apparently it isn't guaranteed. I have decided to use the rufus-scheduler gem, running a Model method every 10mins, although I am concerned that this may impair the apps performance.

Comment: To prevent it impairing you would either need to run it via a rake task or via a worker process (perhaps a clock process) so it runs in it's own process aside from the web process. Also, you may fork the main process and run in a thread along side.

Comment: Could you point me in the direction of some example code which would cover forking the main process?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Heroku scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) to regularly execute a Rake task (or some other script).

Alternatively, if you're checking for Tweets in response to a certain user action or some other event, you could use a task queue like [Delayed Job](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have implemented the rufus-scheduler gem which appears to be a similar solution to your suggestion.